# Setting frame of contained view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using UIViewController containment in an iOS app.  Is there anything special about setting the view controller's view's frame once it's been added to the parent UIViewController?  Or can I just set the view's frame like I would any other subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the contained controller’s view without any extra considerations.